# Sys.Debug messages not appearing in VS debugger Output window

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

This is soooo weird. I cannot seem to get any output messages from Sys.Debug methods to print into the Output window in Visual Studio 2008.

I'm talking about simple things, like **Sys.Debug.trace("show this message")** or **Sys.Debug.traceDump(Sys.UI.DomEvent)**.

They show up in the Firebug trace console just fine. They also show up fine in IE textarea id="TraceConsole".

Why am I not getting any of this to show in the VS debugger console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that you have to debug in IE for this to work. If you debug in a non-IE browser, no joy on the Sys.Debug messages.

I feel so dumb for not having remembered this! ~:/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you can use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine to write to the debugger output window.